# Sort a file using a delimited column

Tags: java

I have a file in below format,

```
Johnny|10|9|6
Smith|1|6|5
Mani|5|3|4
Someone|11|2|12
John|6|10|11
```

So, I want to sort this file in java and I can do this using the below code

```
public class FileComparision {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String inputFile = "C:\\testFile\\result1.txt";

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        String inputLine;
        List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lineList.add(inputLine);
        }
        fileReader.close();

        Collections.sort(lineList);
}
}

The output will be 
John|6|10|11
Johnny|10|9|6
Mani|5|3|4
Someone|11|2|12
Smith|1|6|5
```

So, the code is working fine but the reson for this question is, I want to sort this file on different column, since it is a `|` delimiter column, I want to sort it out using the second or third or may be fourth depending on the user input, is there any way I can achieve this?, like for example if a user want third column as the sorting primary key then the result of the whole file is different than normal.

Comment: Create a class representing one line. Provide your custom `Comparators`

Comment: what if the file contains more than four fields?

Comment: ...and use a CSV library to read the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a class that represent the 4 elements, or just compare using the column index

```
int columnToSort = 2; // between 0 and 3; because it's array index
Collections.sort(l, (o1, o2) -> {
        String[] line1 = o1.split("\\|");
        String[] line2 = o2.split("\\|");
        if(line1.length !=4 || line2.length !=4)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("One line has not the expected size");
        if(line1[columnToSort].matches("\\d+))
            return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(line1[columnToSort]), 
                               Integer.parseInt(line2[columnToSort]));
        else
            return line1[columnToSort].compareTo(line2[columnToSort]);
});
```

note :

- The `if+throw` line are fully optional.
- Using another class will result on a clearer solution, but you don't need help for that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code, but here is the output I am getting `Johnny|10|9|6
John|6|10|11
Smith|1|6|5
Someone|11|2|12
Mani|5|3|4` the output should be `Someone|11|2|12 
Mani|5|3|4 Smith|1|6|5 Johnny|10|9|6 John|6|10|11`

Comment: @GRK I miss that `|` means something different because its regex, so you need to escape. Also you need to parse to int before comparing, because that becomes much code, think about a class next to that

Comment: what if they are not integer and cant we compare it as a string?

Comment: @GRK with "*java developer with more than 7 years of experience*" I hope you will also try by yourself ;)

Comment: what if they are not integer and cant we compare it as a string? even though they are integer values cant we compare as a string?, because we might not know which value will be there at that location in the file, what if they are time stamp?, for the comparison to work do we need to parse it to particular data type?

Comment: @GRK it they are int and compare them as String it will be alphabetical order, fo ex https://ideone.com/4K0Hkc

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @azro, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @GRK azro is right, check line 1140 of String [source code](https://github.com/CyC2018/JDK-Source-Code/blob/master/src/String.java) to see what the default comparison would do. You can't really compare some arbitrary types as Strings.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a model class representing your input (I'm not sure what those values mean so I just called them a, b and c - some meaningful naming is advised indeed):

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

private String name;
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;

public Person(String[] input){
    if(input.length < 4)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input size!");
    name = input[0];
    // note: will throw an Exception if the values cannot be represented as ints
    a = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
    b = Integer.parseInt(input[2]);
    c = Integer.parseInt(input[3]);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getA() {
    return a;
}

public int getB() {
    return b;
}

public int getC() {
    return c;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull Person another) {
    // could be any other property as well
    return Integer.compare(this.a, another.a);
```

Then just split your input into a `String` array by using `inputLine.split("\\|")` and create an `ArrayList<Person>`, then call `Collections.sort(yourList)` on it. Feel free to comment if you need additional guidance.

**EDIT**: as [azro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7212686/azro) pointed out, the default comparator would just sort the Strings alphabetically, check the [String source code line 1140](https://github.com/CyC2018/JDK-Source-Code/blob/master/src/String.java) for details. So you cannot count on Java to compare some arbitrary type represented as a String correctly.

Comment: *I want to sort it out using the second or third or may be fourth depending on the user input* the OP says ;)